# How to check the condition in the jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, dom, strikethrough

I am create the js tree to show the folder path name, and my problem is how to check the condition if database table **status** is 0(inactive) then will show the line-through in the js tree. Else  table **status** is 1(active) just back to normal. Below is my coding:

```html
<?php 
   $folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM filing_code_management");
   $folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(

         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'] . ' ' . "<span id='category'>". $row['category']."</span>",
         "category" => $row['category'],
         "status" => $row['status'], // status 0 is inactive, status 1 is active
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 

      );
   }

   ?> 

<script style="text/javascript">
    var StrikeNodes = function(nodelist) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "text-decoration:" + getStrike(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10));
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        StrikeNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
      });
    };

        var getStrike = function(i) {
      if (status = '0' ) {
        return "line-through;";
      }  else {
        return "";
      }
    };

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      StrikeNodes(tree.get_json());
    });
</script>
```

Now my output show all the all the line-through in the js tree, not detect which is active or inactive.
[image: Output]

My working JSFiddle code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/9x0dsotz/3/

Hope someone can guide me which part I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your code. you are not comparing the status it should be `status == '0'` instead of `status = '0'`

also there is available option that jstree provided. `data` option this can be anything you want. it is metadata you want attached to the nod. you will be able to access and modify it any time later - it has no effect on the visuals of the node.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "100 PENTADBIRAN <span id='category'>JTM<\/span>",
    "category": "JTM",
    "data": { "status": 0 },
    "state": {
        "selected": false,
        "opened": false
    }
}]

var StrikeNodes = function(nodelist) {
  var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
  nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
      tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "text-decoration:" + getStrike(n.data.status);
      tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
      StrikeNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
  });
};

var getStrike = function(status) {
    if (status == 0) {
       return "line-through;";
    }
    return "";
};
```

here's i've edited your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Hafizu/1xt7bhem/11/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you use your code to combine my code above? Because I check my code here, can't work. But your fiddle can work.

Comment: How to set "data": { "status": 0 } to be variable in my code

Comment: hi sorry for late response here you can set status inside data array `"data" => [ "status" => $row['status'] ]`

Comment: Thanks Aslam. Can you help me another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409269/how-to-show-the-color-and-the-strikethrough-at-the-same-time-in-the-js-tree

Comment: My other question need to show the color and strikethrough together