# How to show the color and the strikethrough at the same time in the js tree?

Tags: jquery, node.js, treeview, strikethrough

I have a problem to show the color and the strikethrough at the same time in the js tree. It just can show the color in the js tree, cannot show the strikethrough if the js tree folder name is no active. I have set if the folder name active is 1 , inactive is 0.

Below is my coding, I think these code need to combine to work, but I no idea how to combine it:

```html
<script style="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

    $('#folder_jstree').jstree({
      'core': {
        'data': folder_jsondata,
        'multiple': false
      },
      'plugins': ['sort'],
      'sort': function(a, b) {
        return this.get_text(a).localeCompare(this.get_text(b), 'en', {
          numeric: true
        });
      }
    });

    var getColor = function(i) {
      if (i >= 100 && i <= 199) {
        return "blue";
      } else if (i >= 200 && i <= 299) {
        return "red";
      } else if (i >= 300 && i <= 399) {
        return "yellow";
      } else if (i >= 400 && i <= 499) {
        return "purple";
      } else if (i >= 500 && i <= 599) {
        return "green";
      } else {
        return "#000";
      }
    };

    var colorNodes = function(nodelist) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10));
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        colorNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
      });
    };

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      colorNodes(tree.get_json());
    });

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      $("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.original.category);
    });

  });


  var StrikeNodes = function(nodelist) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "text-decoration:" + getStrike(n.data.status);
        console.log(getStrike(n.data.status))
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        StrikeNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
      });
    };

        var getStrike = function(status) {
      if (status === "0") {
        return "line-through;";
      }  else {
        return "";
      }
    };

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      StrikeNodes(tree.get_json());
    });


</script>
```

This is my php coding:

```html
<?php 
   $folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM filing_code_management");
    // $arr_sql5 = db_conn_select($folderData);
    // foreach ($arr_sql5 as $rs_sql5) {
    // $active = $rs_sql5['status'];
// }


   $folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(

         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'] . ' ' . "<span id='category'>". $row['category']."</span>",
         "category" => $row['category'],
         // "status" => $row['status'], // status 0 is inactive, status 1 is active
         "data" => array("status" => $row['status']) ,
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 

      );
   }

   ?> 

 <!-- Initialize jsTree -->
   <div id="folder_jstree" title=""></div>
   <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
   <textarea style="" id='txt_folderjsondata'><?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?></textarea>
```

My working fs fiddle coding  at here: https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/ng2v75m8/1/

Below sample picture is I want the actual output can show the correct color and the strikethrough if no active.

[image: Output 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code. and this should work as you expect

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

    $('#folder_jstree').jstree({
      'core': {
        'data': folder_jsondata,
        'multiple': false
      },
      'plugins': ['sort'],
      'sort': function(a, b) {
        return this.get_text(a).localeCompare(this.get_text(b), 'en', {
          numeric: true
        });
      }
    });

    $('#folder_jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      $("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.original.category);
    });

});

var StrikeNodes = function(nodelist) {
    var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = getStrike(n);
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        StrikeNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
    });
};

var getStrike = function(n) {

   let { data: { status: stat } } = n
   let color = parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10)

   let isLineThrough = ''
   let theColor = '#000'

   if (stat == 0) isLineThrough = "line-through;";

   if (color >= 100 && color <= 199) {
     theColor = "blue";
   } else if (color >= 200 && color <= 299) {
     theColor = "red";
   } else if (color >= 300 && color <= 399) {
     theColor = "yellow";
   } else if (color >= 400 && color <= 499) {
     theColor = "purple";
   } else if (color >= 500 && color <= 599) {
     theColor = "green";
   }

   return `color: ${theColor}; text-decoration: ${isLineThrough}`;
};

$('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
   var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
   StrikeNodes(tree.get_json());
});
```

also i've edited your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hte5jwx0/

Comment: Thanks Aslam. But without using fiddle I cant work my side. `color: ${theColor}; text-decoration: ${isLineThrough}`.  Is this symbol  `` effect?

Comment: Thanks. I know which part get wrong. Now I have other question similar based on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61451896/how-to-avodi-the-strike-through-in-the-row-content-if-the-status-is-inactive If you have time, can see this question.